# dismess BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have a two BottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment1 and BottomSheetDialogFragment2 and i want to go from BottomSheetDialogFragment1 to BottomSheetDialogFragment2, this is sample like this code

```
    val bottomSheetDialogFragment2 = BottomSheetDialogFragment2()
        bottomSheetDialogFragment2.show(childFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialogFragment1.tag)
```

but when i would dismiss bottomSheetDialogFragment2 after redirecting to to BottomSheetDialogFragment2 like this code

```
        val bottomSheetDialogFragment2 = BottomSheetDialogFragment2()
        bottomSheetDialogFragment2.show(childFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialogFragment1.tag)
```

dismiss()

The result : BottomSheetDialogFragment1 and BottomSheetDialogFragment2 are dismiss() and I like juste to dismiss one BottomSheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Fragment managfer from the activity:

```
  val bottomSheetDialogFragment2 = BottomSheetDialogFragment2()
  bottomSheetDialogFragment2.show(parentFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialogFragment1.tag)
```

Also you can use `showNow` method to prevent a flicker on the screen while transitioning between dialogs:

```
  val bottomSheetDialogFragment2 = BottomSheetDialogFragment2()
  bottomSheetDialogFragment2.showNow(parentFragmentManager,bottomSheetDialogFragment1.tag)
```

beware that `parentFragmentManager` method can throw an exception if you call this method before attaching it to an activity, here is the docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getParentFragmentManager()